# Unable to Assert dual-actioned button in it's disabled and enabled state

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I've a button under one class. They are configured to be dual-actioned.
They are disabled before a certain event. Their DOM while they are disabled:

```
    <div class="doc-buttons">
<a href="#" onclick="actualsize();" id="tip-size" class="left btn btn-white btn-rounded btn-sm icon-size tooltipstered" disabled="disabled">
    <i></i>
</a>
<a href="#" onclick="scaletofit();" id="tip-fit" class="left btn btn-white btn-rounded btn-sm icon-fit tooltipstered" disabled="disabled" style="display: none;">
    <i></i>
</a>
```

...

After a certain event, they are enabled and their DOM changes to:

```
<div class="doc-buttons">
<a href="#" onclick="actualsize();" id="tip-size" class="left btn btn-white btn-rounded btn-sm icon-size tooltipstered">
    <i></i>
</a>
 <a href="#" onclick="scaletofit();" id="tip-fit" class="left btn btn-white btn-rounded btn-sm icon-fit tooltipstered" style="display: none;">
    <i></i>
 </a>
```

...
   ...
   ...

All I have to do is to Assert (using TestNG) that they are enabled and disabled at the right time (sounds pretty simple!)

```
ele1 = _driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='tip-size']"));
ele2 = _driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='tip-fit']"));
```

ele1,2 represent the locator of these button/s.

```
System.out.println("ele1.getAttribute("disabled")");
System.out.println("ele2.getAttribute("disabled")");
```

To my surprise, above print statements always return TRUE irrespective of the state of the buttons (enabled or disabled)

How should I assert them in their disabled and enabled state?

PS: I'm new to WebDriver, Java and TestNG. Any explanation, link to blogs, etc. would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The elements should be re-initialized after the so-called "event".

Steps : 
1. Capture the elements ele1, ele2.

```
ele1.getAttribute("disabled") will be "true/disabled"
ele2.getAttribute("disabled") will be "true/disabled"
```

2. Perform the event (which changes the state of the elements)
3. Now capture the elements once again.

   `ele1 = _driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='tip-size']"))
   ele2 = _driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='tip-fit']"));`
4. Now extract the element properties/attributes.

   `ele1.getAttribute("disabled") should be updated 
   ele2.getAttribute("disabled") should be updated`

Answer (score 1):

Yours should work. Not sure why does not. But, another workaround could be to check if the attribute present with JavaScriptExecutor

```
boolean hasTipSize = (boolean) ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return document.getElementById('tip-size').hasAttribute('disable')");
boolean hasTipFit = (boolean) ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return document.getElementById('tip-fit').hasAttribute('disable')");
```

They should return *true* if `disabled` attribute present else *false*

Comment: I dug more deep. Issue is:
After the event, I add Thread.sleep(2000);
System.out.println("ele1.getAttribute("disabled")");
System.out.println("ele2.getAttribute("disabled")");

Surprisingly, I get null (Earlier I used to get TRUE)

So Webdriver tries to perform getAttribute("disabled") even before the DOM gets loaded completely.
Temporarily, Thread.sleep kind of resolves the issue but it is not a good practice to follow.

Any solution to this?